# importing a database into phpmyadmin #1044 - Access denied for user Can't Edit File

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, text-files

I'm right now trying to upload a 1.3gig sql text file to phpmyadmin and each time I do it I get the following issue.

[my issue](https://gyazo.com/e0630d6660c78962ebbbb2bbedd27971)

I've already tried splitting the file and editing out the CREATE DATABASE line but each time I try opening it in notepad, notepad++ and emeditor I get a bunch of random characters, clearly there's an issue with the encoding. It's not something I can easily export since another company handles that and I have no access to it. I don't care how my SQL text file is opened, I just need a way to view it and I can't find one.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

ISSUE IS SOLVED!!!

Comment: Why on Earth do you you want to restore the mysql database? That's the system database that contains data like users and their privileges.

Comment: There's some data I need to get out of it to potentially fix an issue on a website without having to roll everything back to the 19th.

Comment: I kind of doubt that importing into the system database would resolve an issue with your website. Mysql's system database governs how mysql works, there is no data stored there that would relate to your website. Mysql has various admin tools to troubleshoot issues with its system database. You should only restore the databases relevant to your application.

Comment: Right, which is what I'm trying to do from this database, I'm confident that it contains the information I need to fix an issue. The only issue is is that I'm not sure how to open the file to get the data I need out of it.

Comment: I highly doubt that. The problem is that your user can't access the system database. From the user it seems that you are on a shared provider, and they will never ever allow you to directly access the mysql system database. Rightly so.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create  and then write the database named `mysql`. You Can't Do That™.

You should treat that database, and the `information_schema` and `performance_schema` databases, as readonly. They provide ways to retrieve information about the server via `SELECT` operations. Except in very specific special cases, writing those databases will at best do nothing and at worst trash your server. MySQL tries to prevent you from doing damage by throwing privilege errors when you try to alter those databases.

In a comment you mention that you are confident you can fix an issue with your system via the `mysql` data base. With respect, that's entirely incorrect.

Comment: The biggest issue here is that I haven't told the full story. I'm helping a client reobtain lost custom options for products on a Magento 1.4 website. They provided me with a backup from before the custom options were lost. I may be wrong, but, there should be two ways for me to reobtain that data. One would be to reload the old database but that's in the worst case scenario as we'd lose new orders and client accounts. The best case scenario would be, assuming I'm right which I may not be, to obtain the lost data from the backup provided to me by the client and then reimport that lost data.

Comment: I would like to fully disclose that I don't fully understand MySQL, as is likely evident. So I might just be saying nonsense, but that's also kind of why I'm here, for a bit of guidance to get on the right track. (My work revolves around using CMS's so I never have to deal with the programatic side of working with SQL, or even the side where I have to do something like what I'm talking about right now)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Magento. But a quick search shows that custom options are very likely represented by certain rows in certain tables in the Magento database. Two suggestions (1) https://magento.stackexchange.com/   (2) if your client has access to Magento support, ask them for help.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I figured it all out last night and exported, and reimported, all the data I needed to resolve the issue.